# How to properly use angularjs' ng.rotuter

Tags: angularjs, html

I am a beginner and I can't find what am I doing wrong here, can someone help me?

Below is the code I use

index.html
[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTvQT.png)

```
<body ng-app="psJwtApp">

<!-- Add your site or application content here -->
<div class="header">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a ui-sref="register">Register</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>

    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.config.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

app.config.js (Code for app.config.js)

I use ui.router.
[app.config.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKs0s.png)

```
'use strict';
angular.module('psJwtApp', ['ui.router']).config('psJwtApp', 
function ($stateProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('register', {
        url: '/regiter',
        templateUrl: 'views/register.html'
    })
    .state('home', {
        url: '/ ',
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html'
    });
});
```

Comment: Please replace the image with text. It is much easier for people to try and reconstruct your issue copying and pasting code, rather than reading it from an image. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: try changing: `.config('psJwtApp', function ($stateProvider)` to `.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) ...` it's not necessary to redeclare your app's name here.

Comment: Thank you @SuperVeetz but it's still the same, nothing happened

Comment: do you get any errors? probably a Injector Module Error?

Comment: I would update your question to provide more info than what is currently showing. We don't see the script files to include angular or ui.router. We don't see what app.js contains. Finally, your app.config.js file should be loaded before any other of your app src files, but after angularjs has been included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myApp = angular.module('psJwtApp', ['ui.router']);
myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider.state("home", {
        url: "#",
        templateUrl: "home.html",
        controller: "HomeCtrl"
      }).state("register", {
        url: "#",
        templateUrl: "register.html",
        controller: "registerCtrl"
      });
});
myApp.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}])
myApp.controller('registerCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
})
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/sdkZ02asCTGsx8Uk4VFO?p=preview)